# As soon as I add a project to XCode 4.0.2 it crashes

Tags: xcode4

It gives this error:

```
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-269/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/PBXContainerItemProxy.m:268
Details:  Assertion failed: _containerPortal == [self container] || ([_containerPortal isKindOfClass:[PBXFileReference class]] && [(PBXFileReference *)_containerPortal container] == [self container])
Object:   <PBXContainerItemProxy: 0x2017db420>
Method:   -_containerPortal
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x200020700>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x0000000100949773 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x000000010006d394 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000010d4a15c7 -[PBXContainerItemProxy _containerPortal] (in DevToolsCore)
  3  0x000000010d3deefb -[PBXArchivingBinding writeValueForObject:toPListArchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
  4  0x000000010d3dde4e -[PBXObject _archiveValuesForArchiveMask:toPListArchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
  5  0x000000010d40b52a -[PBXPListArchiver _archiveObject:asWeakReference:] (in DevToolsCore)
  6  0x000000010d40dea8 -[PBXPListArchiver _encodeObject:forKey:asWeakReference:] (in DevToolsCore)
  7  0x000000010d3df0b2 -[PBXArchivingBinding writeValueForObject:toPListArchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
  8  0x000000010d3dde4e -[PBXObject _archiveValuesForArchiveMask:toPListArchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
  9  0x000000010d4461c0 -[PBXTargetDependency writeToPListArchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
 10  0x000000010d40b52a -[PBXPListArchiver _archiveObject:asWeakReference:] (in DevToolsCore)
 11  0x000000010d40e212 -[PBXPListArchiver _createPListArrayForObjectArray:asWeakReference:] (in DevToolsCore)
 12  0x000000010d40ea15 -[PBXPListArchiver _encodeObjectArray:forKey:asWeakReference:] (in DevToolsCore)
 13  0x000000010d3df0b2 -[PBXArchivingBinding writeValueForObject:toPListArchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
 14  0x000000010d3dde4e -[PBXObject _archiveValuesForArchiveMask:toPListArchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
 15  0x000000010d40b52a -[PBXPListArchiver _archiveObject:asWeakReference:] (in DevToolsCore)
 16  0x000000010d40e212 -[PBXPListArchiver _createPListArrayForObjectArray:asWeakReference:] (in DevToolsCore)
 17  0x000000010d40ea15 -[PBXPListArchiver _encodeObjectArray:forKey:asWeakReference:] (in DevToolsCore)
 18  0x000000010d3df0b2 -[PBXArchivingBinding writeValueForObject:toPListArchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
 19  0x000000010d3dde4e -[PBXObject _archiveValuesForArchiveMask:toPListArchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
 20  0x000000010d40b52a -[PBXPListArchiver _archiveObject:asWeakReference:] (in DevToolsCore)
 21  0x000000010d40c1b7 -[PBXPListArchiver initWithRootObject:delegate:role:] (in DevToolsCore)
 22  0x000000010d40c4ac -[PBXPListArchiver initWithRootObject:delegate:] (in DevToolsCore)
 23  0x000000010d3e675d -[PBXProject writeToFile:projectFile:userFile:outResultNotification:] (in DevToolsCore)
 24  0x000000010d3e6d42 -[PBXProject _writeToFileSystemProjectFile:userFile:checkNeedsRevert:] (in DevToolsCore)
 25  0x000000010d3e6df6 -[PBXProject writeToFileSystemProjectFile:userFile:checkNeedsRevert:] (in DevToolsCore)
 26  0x000000010d3653ea -[Xcode3Project writeToFilePath:forceWrite:error:] (in Xcode3Core)
 27  0x000000010051e47e -[IDEContainer _saveContainerForAction:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
 28  0x00007fff8231b7d5 __NSFireTimer (in Foundation)
 29  0x00007fff81173be8 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 30  0x00007fff81171dbf CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 31  0x00007fff823007c4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] (in Foundation)
 32  0x00007fff8234bf36 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] (in Foundation)
 33  0x00007fff83a73e0b NSCoreDragReceiveProc (in AppKit)
 34  0x00007fff81a8a2c3 DoDropMessage (in HIServices)
 35  0x00007fff81a8b4f2 CoreDragMessageHandler (in HIServices)
 36  0x00007fff811d95e1 __CFMessagePortPerform (in CoreFoundation)
 37  0x00007fff811736e1 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 38  0x00007fff81171dbf CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 39  0x00007fff84ea67ee RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 40  0x00007fff84ea6551 ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 41  0x00007fff84ea64ac BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode (in HIToolbox)
 42  0x00007fff83732e64 _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 43  0x00007fff837327a9 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 44  0x00007fff836f848b -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 45  0x00007fff836f11a8 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 46  0x0000000100000eec
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is due to the new version of XCodeProjects.  I found a work around by pre-compiling the library that was causing the issue and then using the linker to link to the .a file.  I also had to copy the .a library into the DerivedData path.

The real solution was to remove the project and replace it with an updated project for the new version of XCode.

Answer (score 1):

Even worse, though I'd remove that project, crash had occurred repeatedly in my case.
I fixed this problem by editing project.pbxproj(in .xcodeproject file) manually.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by going back to a backup of the project.pbxproj. After that I removed the library that was causing the issue (reference only). Added the library to the project again and deleted the DerivedData.