# Xcode upgrade: PBXContainerItemProxy missing containerPortal key

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I just upgraded my Xcode, now when I try to open my project, I get this error:

> Project /Users/xxx/xxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxxxx.xcodeproj cannot be opened: PBXContainerItemProxy (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx) is missing a containerPortal key

I have searched the web and stackoverflow, but cannot get anything relevent to come up at all regarding this.

I do have Three20 as part of my project, I don't know if that matters. I just upgraded to xcode 4.4.1

Thanks for any insight.

-D

Comment: Solved same error in my case :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the project icon which we see i.e projectname.xcodeproj, is actually a directory, you do this

1. in terminal do cd yourproject.xcodeproj
2.ls
3.vi  project.pbxproj
4. scroll down till /* Begin PBXContainerItemProxy section */
5.there you will see all sections check for the section which is missing a portal key edit it and save it :wq it will work

[image: Screen shot]

in image if you see the first section is missing container portal key.just pic it from other section and replace it..

it will work :D  see this [link](http://www.amarendrasingh.com/objective-c/xcode-upgrade-pbxcontaineritemproxy-missing-containerportal-key/)

Comment: Wow, thanks, that was it! So simple. Of course I was well down theroad of creating a whole new project in 3.2, then bringing that into 4.whatever, then dealing with the millions of new errors (almost a month later, and still hadn't gotten something that worked well enough to get to the app store....) - Bnd this worked right off he bat! I don't know if you will get the bounty for this, you deserve it. If there is a way to transfer points, I will do it.

Comment: Buddy if it helped you its enough for me thanku :) and god speed

Comment: None are missing it for me. And the one it gives an error for has it. (RCTRestart.xcodeproject) in react native

Comment: @JeremyF Somehow always lose track of cause and effect while working on any hybrid solution... won't be of much help

Answer (score 0):

Now I should start with that I do not know the actual error, never seen it before, but I did find a reference to a "PBXContainerProxy"-error in this post ([As soon as I add a project to XCode 4.0.2 it crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794704/as-soon-as-i-add-a-project-to-xcode-4-0-2-it-crashes)) and thought you might try the solutions from there?

> "Apparently this is due to the new version of XCodeProjects. I found a
>   work around by pre-compiling the library that was causing the issue
>   and then using the linker to link to the .a file. I also had to copy
>   the .a library into the DerivedData path.
>
> The real solution was to remove the project and replace it with an
>   updated project for the new version of XCode."

Hope that helps somewhat :)

Comment: I appreciate the help, I saw the same post. If I may vent, I'm not sure what part of "keep it simple stupid" Apple doesn't understand, but their approach is getting completely schizophrenic. On the one hand they are making goofy "Storyboards" so that seemingly a child could build an app, and on the other hand are getting so opaque and complicated, you have to have a CS Masters degree to figure this sh--tuff out. I'm at my wit's end. I built a really complex app which has sold a few thousand copies in XCode 3.2, now it's like I'm starting from scratch. And at ever turn a new glitch. Sucks. Thx

Comment: Sorry to hear that. And sorry I can't be of more help :-/

Answer (score 0):

Never saw that error either, but if you're upgrading directly from XCode 3.X I'd suggest you to go to https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode

and download/install a previous version of Xcode somewhere else. (You can have several different copies installed on your machine, just google it if you don't know how but just remember to use xcode-select to pick the one you want to use). Repeat with all the versions back to 4.0.1 until (hopefully) it works. I know it's tedious but it might help.

If it does, validate the project settings and try to open it with 4.4.1. That should work.

Good luck

Comment: What do you mean by validating project settings can you please explain?Ihave upgraded from xcode 4.2 to 4.5

Comment: @amar I mean click on the "Validate Settings" button (the one with clock icon) shown at when you select your project in the navigator