# containerPortal is NULL xcode Assertion Failure

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

After I've upgraded rect-native project from [0.57.0 => 0.59.10](https://github.com/react-native-community/rn-diff-purge/compare/release/0.57.0..release/0.59.10) I have a problem opening my project in xcode.

Full stacktrace on `react-native run-ios --verbose`

```
➜ react-native run-ios --verbose
info Found Xcode project Hub.xcodeproj
info Building using "xcodebuild -project Hub.xcodeproj -configuration Debug -scheme Hub -destination id=983F7ABF-6770-4DB6-B13C-2606DA4BF6C1 -derivedDataPath build/Hub"
info User defaults from command line:
    IDEDerivedDataPathOverride = /Users/petarpilipovic/Documents/Project/hub-family-mobile/ios/build/Hub


error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code null. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening Hub.xcodeproj

2019-07-26 19:20:15.011 xcodebuild[79690:6745260] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-14492.1/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/ProjectModel/DataModel/Containers/PBXContainerItemProxy.m:136
Details:  _containerPortal is NULL
Object:   <PBXContainerItemProxy: 0x7fe8897ad3a0>
Method:   -remoteContainer
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fe886c058f0>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints:

Backtrace:
  0   -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation)
  1   _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3   -[PBXContainerItemProxy remoteContainer] (in DevToolsCore)
  4   -[PBXContainerItemProxy remoteContainerItem] (in DevToolsCore)
  5   -[PBXReferenceProxy sourceTree] (in DevToolsCore)
  6   -[PBXReference addNotifications] (in DevToolsCore)
  7   -[PBXReference awakeFromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
  8   -[PBXReferenceProxy awakeFromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
  9   -[PBXPListUnarchiver decodeRootObject] (in DevToolsCore)
 10   +[PBXProject projectWithFile:errorHandler:readOnly:] (in DevToolsCore)
 11   -[PBXFileReference loadedContainer] (in DevToolsCore)
 12   -[PBXContainerItemProxy remoteContainer] (in DevToolsCore)
 13   -[PBXContainerItemProxy remoteContainerItem] (in DevToolsCore)
 14   -[PBXReferenceProxy sourceTree] (in DevToolsCore)
 15   -[PBXReference addNotifications] (in DevToolsCore)
 16   -[PBXReference awakeFromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
 17   -[PBXReferenceProxy awakeFromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
 18   -[PBXPListUnarchiver decodeRootObject] (in DevToolsCore)
 19   +[PBXProject projectWithFile:errorHandler:readOnly:] (in DevToolsCore)
 20   -[Xcode3Project initWithFilePath:extension:workspace:options:error:] (in DevToolsCore)
 21   __82+[IDEContainer _retainedContainerAtFilePath:fileDataType:workspace:options:error:]_block_invoke_2 (in IDEFoundation)
 22   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 23   _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete (in libdispatch.dylib)
 24   DVTDispatchBarrierSync (in DVTFoundation)
 25   -[DVTDispatchLock performLockedBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
 26   __82+[IDEContainer _retainedContainerAtFilePath:fileDataType:workspace:options:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEFoundation)
 27   __58-[DVTModelObjectGraph performBlockCoalescingModelChanges:]_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
 28   -[DVTModelGraphTransactionScope performTransaction:] (in DVTFoundation)
 29   -[DVTModelObjectGraph performBlockCoalescingModelChanges:] (in DVTFoundation)
 30   +[IDEContainer _retainedContainerAtFilePath:fileDataType:workspace:options:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
 31   +[IDEContainer retainedContainerAtFilePath:fileDataType:workspace:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
 32   -[IDEWorkspace _configureWrappedWorkspaceWithError:] (in IDEFoundation)
 33   __82+[IDEContainer _retainedContainerAtFilePath:fileDataType:workspace:options:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEFoundation)
 34   +[IDEContainer _retainedContainerAtFilePath:fileDataType:workspace:options:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
 35   +[IDEContainer retainedWrappedWorkspaceForContainerAtFilePath:fileDataType:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
 36   -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool _resolveInputOptionsWithTimingSection:] (in Xcode3Core)
 37   -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool run] (in Xcode3Core)
 38   main (in xcodebuild)
 39   start (in libdyld.dylib)

debug Error: Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code null. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening Hub.xcodeproj

2019-07-26 19:20:15.011 xcodebuild[79690:6745260] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-14492.1/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/ProjectModel/DataModel/Containers/PBXContainerItemProxy.m:136
Details:  _containerPortal is NULL
Object:   <PBXContainerItemProxy: 0x7fe8897ad3a0>
Method:   -remoteContainer
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fe886c058f0>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints:

Backtrace:
  0   -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation)
  1   _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3   -[PBXContainerItemProxy remoteContainer] (in DevToolsCore)
  4   -[PBXContainerItemProxy remoteContainerItem] (in DevToolsCore)
  5   -[PBXReferenceProxy sourceTree] (in DevToolsCore)
  6   -[PBXReference addNotifications] (in DevToolsCore)
  7   -[PBXReference awakeFromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
  8   -[PBXReferenceProxy awakeFromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
  9   -[PBXPListUnarchiver decodeRootObject] (in DevToolsCore)
 10   +[PBXProject projectWithFile:errorHandler:readOnly:] (in DevToolsCore)
 11   -[PBXFileReference loadedContainer] (in DevToolsCore)
 12   -[PBXContainerItemProxy remoteContainer] (in DevToolsCore)
 13   -[PBXContainerItemProxy remoteContainerItem] (in DevToolsCore)
 14   -[PBXReferenceProxy sourceTree] (in DevToolsCore)
 15   -[PBXReference addNotifications] (in DevToolsCore)
 16   -[PBXReference awakeFromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
 17   -[PBXReferenceProxy awakeFromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
 18   -[PBXPListUnarchiver decodeRootObject] (in DevToolsCore)
 19   +[PBXProject projectWithFile:errorHandler:readOnly:] (in DevToolsCore)
 20   -[Xcode3Project initWithFilePath:extension:workspace:options:error:] (in DevToolsCore)
 21   __82+[IDEContainer _retainedContainerAtFilePath:fileDataType:workspace:options:error:]_block_invoke_2 (in IDEFoundation)
 22   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 23   _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete (in libdispatch.dylib)
 24   DVTDispatchBarrierSync (in DVTFoundation)
 25   -[DVTDispatchLock performLockedBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
 26   __82+[IDEContainer _retainedContainerAtFilePath:fileDataType:workspace:options:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEFoundation)
 27   __58-[DVTModelObjectGraph performBlockCoalescingModelChanges:]_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
 28   -[DVTModelGraphTransactionScope performTransaction:] (in DVTFoundation)
 29   -[DVTModelObjectGraph performBlockCoalescingModelChanges:] (in DVTFoundation)
 30   +[IDEContainer _retainedContainerAtFilePath:fileDataType:workspace:options:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
 31   +[IDEContainer retainedContainerAtFilePath:fileDataType:workspace:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
 32   -[IDEWorkspace _configureWrappedWorkspaceWithError:] (in IDEFoundation)
 33   __82+[IDEContainer _retainedContainerAtFilePath:fileDataType:workspace:options:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEFoundation)
 34   +[IDEContainer _retainedContainerAtFilePath:fileDataType:workspace:options:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
 35   +[IDEContainer retainedWrappedWorkspaceForContainerAtFilePath:fileDataType:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
 36   -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool _resolveInputOptionsWithTimingSection:] (in Xcode3Core)
 37   -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool run] (in Xcode3Core)
 38   main (in xcodebuild)
 39   start (in libdyld.dylib)

    at ChildProcess.buildProcess.on.code (/Users/petarpilipovic/Documents/Project/hub-family-mobile/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/runIOS/runIOS.js:231:16)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:389:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:606:12).
```

I found out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12580044/4107823) that maybe I'm missing a portal key so I've inspected `project.pbxproj` in the `/* Begin PBXContainerItemProxy section */` section, keys are there and all seems to be ok. I've also [removed](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23886?source=post_page---------------------------#issuecomment-473983890) 
xcode delivered data cache, bit no joy. What else can I do?

Comment: any luck?  I am having a similar if not the same issue.

Comment: yes, it's a bit complicated but, I have cloned the repo opened my `project.pbxproj` and I have added missing JavaScriptCore.framework, so DONT edit project.pbxproj in editor.

Answer (score 1):

Incase this happens to anyone else....

This occurred for me after upgrading versions of React Native (from a version that did not use cocoapods, to a version that did).

It seems the problem occurred as Xcode attempts to link the cocoapods, and I needed to delete the old dependency links (from `react-native link`).

I did this by deleting broken dep links from Target > Project > Build Phases >  Link Binary with Libraries

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If You use `cocoapods` then you should always use this file:

```
yourProjectDir/ios/yourprojectname.xcworkspace
```